# FireBeetle-ESP32 and mklittlefs parameters

Tags: esp32, spiffs

I'm using a [DFRobot FireBeetle-ESP32](https://wiki.dfrobot.com/FireBeetle_ESP32_IOT_Microcontroller(V3.0)__Supports_Wi-Fi_&_Bluetooth__SKU__DFR0478) with spiffs and I downloaded the [esp32 boards file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/master/boards.txt) looking for the spiffs parameters `block size`, `page size`, `spiffs start` and `spiffs end` as I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.coldreactor.com/2018/12/29/ESP8266-SPIFFS-Manual.html) but for the ESP32, i.e.

```
mklittlefs --size <image size> --page <page size> --block <block size> -d 5 --create ./data spiffs.bin
```

The ESP32 boards file doesn't contain that information. Is there anywhere it's available in order to use mkspiffs? Or are there reasonable defaults for the FireBeetle-ESP32?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the parameters by installing the [arduino-esp32fs-plugin](https://github.com/lorol/arduino-esp32fs-plugin).

First need to find where to put the plugin. This is on a Raspberry Pi 4.

```
Arduino IDE -> File -> Preferences -> Sketchbook location
```

which is `/home/pi/Arduino`

Download the plugin and put it in:

```
/home/pi/Arduino/tools/ESP32FS/tool/esp32fs.jar
```

restart the Arduino IDE, load the [LITTLEFS_test](https://github.com/lorol/LITTLEFS/tree/master/examples/LITTLEFS_test) example and save it to a suitable location, e.g.:

```
/home/pi/dev/esp32/LITTLEFS_test/LITTLEFS_test.ino
/home/pi/dev/esp32/LITTLEFS_test/partitions.csv
```

then create a data directory and file with some content in the sketch directory:

```
/home/pi/dev/esp32/LITTLEFS_test/data/test.txt
```

then in the Arduino IDE:

```
Tools -> ESP32 Sketch Data Upload
```

choose `LittleFS` and `OK`.

The required data is then in the output window of the Arduino IDE:

```
[LittleFS] data   : /home/pi/dev/esp32/LittleFS_test/data
[LittleFS] offset : 0
[LittleFS] start  : 2162688
[LittleFS] size   : 1856
[LittleFS] page   : 256
[LittleFS] block  : 4096
```

I added some debug output to the plugin, compiled it and put it in the Arduino IDE to come up with a commandline version. Note that the `size` parameter in the Arduino IDE output window is divided by `1024`, so need to multiply it by `1024` for the commandline version:

```
 /home/pi/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/mklittlefs/3.0.4-gcc10.3-1757bed/mklittlefs -c ./data2 -p 256 -b 4096 -s 1507328 spiffs.bin
```

installing esptool:

```
pip install esptool
```

and adding more debug output to the plugin gave me the commandline for uploading the littlefs image:

```
python -m esptool --chip esp32 --baud 921600 --port /dev/ttyUSB0 --before default_reset --after hard_reset write_flash -z --flash_mode dio --flash_freq 80m --flash_size detect 2686976 spiffs.bin
```